# Seeding users in Startup file in EF core: Dependency Injection Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have the following `SampleData` class to generate some user data after running `EF Migration`.

```
namespace App.Models
{
    public interface ISampleData
    {
        void Initialize();
    }
    public class SampleData: ISampleData
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

        public SampleData(
            AppDbContext context,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager
            )
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }


        public void Initialize()
        {
            ApplicationUser user;

            IdentityRole myrole = _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Admin").Result;

            if (myrole != null) return;

            IdentityResult result = _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "Admin".ToUpper() }).Result;
            string userId1 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    Id = userId1.ToString(),
                    UserName = "erkanererkaner@gmail.com",
                    Email = "erkanererkaner@gmail.com",
                    FirstName = "Erkan",
                    LastName = "Er"
                };

                result = _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "123456Aa*").Result;
                if (result.Succeeded) _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin").Wait();
            }   
        }                    
    }
}
```

The `Initialize()` method is caled from `Startup` file, like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly ISampleData _sampleData;
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ISampleData sampleData)
    {
        _sampleData = sampleData;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //other implementation details

        services.AddScoped<ISampleData, SampleData>(); 
    }
}
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider services)
    {
        //other implementation details

        _sampleData.Initialize();
    }
```

However, I got the following error:

> Using application service provider from IWebHost accessor on
>   'Program'. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service
>   for type 'App.Models.ISampleData' while attempting to activate
>   'App.Startup'.    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
>   provider)

I see that this is about the way I implemented `Dependency Injection`. But I cannot see the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot inject types other than `IConfiguration` and `IHostingEnvironment` in your Startup constructor. The reason for this is that the Startup class actually configures the dependency injection container first (through the `ConfigureServices` method). So at the time you want to resolve the dependencies (in the constructor), the whole DI infrastructure does not even exist yet.

Instead, you can resolve the services earliest within the `Configure` method, which gets called *after* the dependency injection container is created. You can actually add dependencies directly in the method signature to have them resolved automatically:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ISampleData sampleData)
{
    // …

    sampleData.Initialize();
}
```

Note that for seeding your database, it is generally not recommended to do that withint he `Configure` method since that may run in situations where you don’t want to seed your database yet (for example, when you are doing integration tests, or when you call `dotnet ef` from the command line).

Instead, the recommended pattern for seeding the database is to do that outside of the Startup but at the web host level instead. So inside of your `Program` class, you could modify it like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create web host
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

        // create service scope for seeding the database
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            // retrieve the sample data service
            var sampleData = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISampleData>();

            // run your sample data initialization
            _sampleData.Initialize();
        }

        // run the application
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
        => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Comment: With this approach, will it try to create the same data by calling `_sampleData.Initialize();` each time the program is run?

Comment: Yeah, the `Initialize` runs whenever the application starts (just like when you would call it within the `Configure` method). So you should build your service so that it checks whether it has to seed the data, and only create it when it isn’t already there.